# What is the most efficient strategy?

Tags: jurassic-world-the-game

So in the mobile game Jurassic World the game you are charged with maintaining a park, growing your Dino's by feeding them and battling with a custom team of Dino's of your choosing. I run a basic early game team of a 2-star level 24 mujangasaurus, 2-star level 21 trike, and a 1-star level 14 tropeognathus. In a battle you have your attack, block and reserves. What is the most efficient battle strategy and and who should I have out first, second and third?